# ASP .NET MVC anti-forgery token value, not HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I'd like to obtain anti-forgery token value in ASP .NET MVC project. I have investigated the [`HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken` helper method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175) only to find that it uses the [`AntiForgery` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery) which provides public method `GetHtml` used by the aforementioned helper. The problem is this method only returns the HTML of the entire hidden form input field represented by `HtmlString`. I'd like to get my hand on the name of the field and its value, which I am able to do now parsing the returned `HtmlString`, but not in any clear way. Everything useful (like `IAntiForgeryConfig` implementation for the field name) is internal. Is there any other facet of the MVC infrastructure that I am not aware of that offers public members allowing the access to the form field name and value rather that the serialized values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the method I was after was hidden in a plain sight. The `AntiForgery` class provides a public method called `GetTokens` which is what I need.